# Failed to load resource ...bundle.js when trying to deploy to gh-pages

Tags: angular, github, github-pages

I'm receiving the following errors when trying to deploy an Angular 5 app to gh pages.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

main.1882bffa287469f2bff7.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

polyfills.bf95165a1d5098766b92.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

naeroled.github.io/:1 Refused to apply style from 'https://github.com/naeroled/styles.c3420b183364b4c85cc5.bundle.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

inline.318b50c57b4eba3d437b.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
naeroled.github.io/:1 Refused to apply style from 'https://github.com/naeroled/styles.c3420b183364b4c85cc5.bundle.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

polyfills.bf95165a1d5098766b92.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

main.1882bffa287469f2bff7.bundle.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

naeroled.github.io/:1 Refused to apply style from 'https://github.com/naeroled/styles.c3420b183364b4c85cc5.bundle.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

I've installed angular-cli-ghpages completed the build. Of course it states successfully published. I'm using MDBootstrap for some styling. Not sure if thats the issue or not.

Comment: try angular cli's official docs here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-github-pages. But keep in mind the build command should be ng build --prod --output-path docs --base-href /PROJECT_NAME/ , not just ng build --prod --output-path docs --base-href PROJECT_NAME, the two slashes are needed.